# October CMS backend form field get backend username

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend, october-partial

How can I get the backend user's name and output it on the backend form field using a partial.

Thanks
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every partials which are render in back-end has "user" object within in it.

and this object is pointing to current logged in back-end user.

so if you want to add that user's **fisrt_name** in partial you can do something like this.

```
<?= $this->user->first_name ?>
```

but from you code I can sense that you want to use use-name and try to use it as **key** for **$value** array and get inner value of **$value** array

so first {{ }} this will **not** work inside  php tags, instead good news you can directly use php code there :)

your solution:

```
<?= $value[$this->user->fisrt_name] ?>
```

you can replace attribute **first_name** to another column attribute which will appropriate to you.

if any issue please do comment.

Answer (score 0):

// Returns the signed in user
$user = BackendAuth::getUser();

// Returns the signed in user from a controller
$user = $this->user;